# In which case is if(a=b) a good idea?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Inadvertent use of = instead of ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of)

C++ compilers let you know via warnings that you wrote,

```
if( a = b ) { //...
```

And that it might be a mistake that you certainly wanted to write:

```
if( a == b ) { //...
```

But is there a case where the warning should be ignored, because it's a good way to use this "feature"?
I don't see any code clarity reason possible, so is there a case where it’s useful?

Comment: Some compilers will not issue warning if the assignment is enclosed by double parentheses, likes so: if (( a = b ))

Comment: Note that this question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of

Comment: if( a = b ){.....}

and 

a = b;
if(a) {....}

are same. so it's not an error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two possible reasons:

1. **Assign & Check**

   The `=` operator (when not overriden) normally returns the value that it assigned. This is to allow statements such as `a=b=c=3`. In the context of your question, it also allows you to do something like this:

   ```
   bool global;//a global variable

   //a function
   int foo(bool x){

      //assign the value of x to global
      //if x is equal to true, return 4
      if (global=x)
          return 4;

      //otherwise return 3
      return 3;
   }
   ```

   ...which is equivalent to but shorter than:

   ```
   bool global;//a global variable

   //a function
   int foo(bool x){

      //assign the value of x to global
      global=x;

      //if x is equal to true, return 4
      if (global==true)
          return 4;

      //otherwise return 3
      return 3;
   }
   ```

   Also, it should be noted (as stated by Billy ONeal in a comment below) that this can also work when the left-hand argument of the `=` operator is actually a class with a [conversion operator](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12459) specified for a type which can be coerced (implicitly converted) to a bool. In other words, `(a=b)` will evaulate to `true` or `false` if a is of a type which can be coerced to a boolean value.

   So the following is a similar situation to the above, except the left-hand argument to `=` is an object and not a bool:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   class Foo {
   public:
       operator bool (){ return true; }
       Foo(){}
   };

   int main(){
       Foo a;
       Foo b;

       if (a=b)
           cout<<"true";
       else
           cout<<"false";
   }

   //output: true
   ```

   *Note:* At the time of this writing, the code formatting above is bugged. My code (check the source) actually features proper indenting, shift operators and line spacing. The `&lt;`'s are supposed to be <'s, and there aren't supposed to be enourmous gaps between each line.
2. **Overridden `=` operator**

   Since C++ allows the overriding of operators, sometimes = will be overriden to do something other than what it does with primitive types. In these cases, the performing the `=` operation on an object could return a boolean (if that's how the `=` operator was overridden for that object type).

   So the following code would perform the `=` operation on `a` with `b` as an argument. Then it would conditionally execute some code depending on the return value of that operation:

   ```
   if (a=b){
      //execute some code
   }
   ```

   Here, `a` would have to be an object and `b` would be of the correct type as defined by the overriding of the `=` operator for objects of `a`'s type. To learn more about operator overriding, see this wikipedia article which includes C++ examples: [Wikipedia article on operator overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading)

Comment: As an amendment to "Sign and Check", keep in mind that the type can have an `operator bool()` override.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I'd like to add that to my answer if it's alright - that's a great point. However perhaps it should be its own item in the list rather than an addition to 1 or 2?

Comment: I'd argue that the second form (overriding = to return a boolean) is terrible, evil, ugly, and makes you a bad person.

Comment: @Steven Schlansker: Why? 'Returns 0 on failure, 1 on success' seems like a reasonable (albeit simple) way to overload `=`. Not trying to be oppositional, just curious as to why you think that.

Comment: Because everyone expects a=b to return the value itself.  Imagine trying to write a=b=c=d; when you want to assign a bunch of variables to each other... and then figuring out ten hours of bug-busting later that b=c returned 1 instead of c!  It violates the general contract of the = operator.

Comment: @incrediman: Please feel free to add to your answer lol. Put it how you see fit. @Steven: +1 to your comments -- good points.

Comment: @Billy: Good stuff - if you're wondering why I asked, I figured you might post it as your own answer instead :)

Comment: @Steven Schlansker: I agree for the *vast majority* of cases, but there are times where a boolean return value for the `=` operator can be useful. Therefore I disagree with the accross-the-board notion that `operator bool ()` is bad. A counter-example for your argument would be an OOP wrapper class for the `bool` type - having the `=` operator return a `bool` value would be appropriate.

Comment: I think that falls squarely on the "too much" side of "too much magic" for my tastes.  But then again, there's a reason I avoid C++ entirely :-p

Comment: I fixed your code to what obviously was your intention. You were just assigning pointers and boolean-evaluated their addresses

Comment: @Johannes Schlaub - litb: Actually what I meant was for this to be the conditional: `*(a=b)`, but what you've put there is simpler anyways, so I'll leave it that way :)

Answer (score 11):

```
while ( (line = readNextLine()) != EOF) {
    processLine();
}
```

Comment: That's not really the same sort of situation, though, since you're not directly using the assignment as the test.

Comment: No, it is indeed the same situation: assignment result as the evaluation expression of the if() statement.

Comment: No, it's an assignment result used as the left side of a comparison expression which is used as the evaluation expression of the if statement. It's objectively not the same thing because the compiler will never warn about this form.

Comment: In my defense, the question wasn't at all specific that he didn't want forms other than the simple assignment.

Comment: It is still the same situation: an assignment is always a valid expression for the evaluation of conditional statements.

Comment: This is not the same situation.  The actual if conditional is evaluated with the `!=` comparism.

Answer (score 8):

You could use to test if a function returned any error:

```
if (error_no = some_function(...)) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Assuming that *some_function* returns the error code in case of an error. Or zero otherwise.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you can't put the assignment before the conditional.

Comment: You can put the assignment before but that was not the question.

Comment: @Ed: yes, this was the question. it was about whether or not it is a good idea to place it there. you made no cause for a good idea, but you just show a syntactically valid case. it easily can be done differently, with no overhead at all if you have a decent compiler.

Answer (score 6):

This is a consequence of basic feature of the C language:

> *The value of an assignment operation is the assigned value itself*.

The fact that you can use that "return value" as the condition of an `if()` statement is incidental.

By the way, this is the same trick that allows this crazy conciseness:

```
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
    while( *s++ = *t++ );
}
```

Of course, the while exits when the nullchar in `t` is reached, but at the same time it is copied to the destination `s` string.

Whether it is a good idea, usually not, as it reduce code readability and is prone to errors.

Comment: You may wish to consider changing "basic feature of the C language" to "basic feature of the C++ language" since that seems to be the primary focus of the question (although it was also tagged as `c`, so it's up to you).

Comment: It IS a feature of the C language, inherited by C++. In my opinion the flaw is in the question, as it seems to suggest that this is a C++ only feature. Therefore, it should be edited the question at least as "C/C++".

Comment: By that reasoning, you can say "basic feature of B" or whatever stone-age language in a discussion about whatever common concept of a particular language, and ask the questioner about changing all language questions about C or C++ to B. I think this is not eligible. C++ and C, like C and B are different langauges.

Comment: @ Johannes: weak argument, as B is a dead language, while C is still one of the most used languages. Then, when something applies to both C and C++ it is very common to say that it is a C/C++ topic. Only when a topic applies **ONLY** to C++ you call it a C++ topic.

Answer (score 3):

Although the construct is perfectly legal syntax and *your* intent may truly be as shown below, don't leave the "!= 0" part out.

```
if( (a = b) != 0 ) {
   ...
}
```

The person looking at the code 6 months, 1 year, 5 years from now, at first glance, is simply going to believe the code contains a "classic bug" written by a junior programmer and will try to "fix" it.  The construct above *clearly* indicates your intent and will be optimized out by the compiler. This would be especially embarrassing if *you* are that person.

Your other option is to heavily load it with comments. But the above is self-documenting code, which is better.

Lastly, my preference is to do this:

```
a = b;
if( a != 0 ) {
   ...
}
```

This is about a clear as the code can get. If there is a performance hit, it is virtually zero.

Answer (score 2):

I know that with this syntax you can avoid putting an extra line in your code, but I think it takes away some readability from the code.

This syntax is very useful for things like the one suggested by [Steven Schlansker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122284/in-which-case-is-ifa-b-a-good-idea/3122290#3122290), but using it directly as a condition isn't a good idea.

Comment: +1: It is widely recognised that using any form of "side effect" in a condition is a bad coding style, because it is proven to increase bug rates (every small thing that makes code more complex or less readable, even only by the slightest amount, contributes in this way). This is why you get a compiler WARNING for such code.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually a deliberate feature of C, but a consequence of two other features:

**Assignment returns the assigned value**

This is useful for performing multiple assignments, like `a = b = 0`, or loops like `while ((n = getchar()) != EOF)`.

**Numbers and pointers have truth values**

C originally didn't have a `bool` type until the [1999 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), so it used `int` to represent Boolean values.  Backwards compatibility requires C and C++ to allow non-`bool` expressions in `if`, `while`, and `for`.

So, if `a = b` has a value and `if` is lenient about what values it accepts, then `if (a = b)` works.  But I'd recommend using `if ((a = b) != 0)` instead to discourage anyone from "fixing" it.

Answer (score 2):

A common example where it is useful might be:

```
do {
 ...
} while (current = current->next);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly write the checking statement in a better coding manner, avoiding the *assign & check* approach. Example:

```
if ((fp = fopen("filename.txt", "wt")) != NULL) {
    // Do something with fp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while( (l = getline()) != EOF){
        printf("%s\n", l);
}
```

This is of course the simplest example, and there are lots of times when this is useful. The primary thing to remember is that (a = true) returns true, just as (a = false) returns false.

Comment: Never use lowercase L as a variable name.

Comment: This is what I thought at first, but I don't think this applies to the question.
I think in this scenario the compiler doesn't display the warning (I might be wrong though).

Comment: In C99, such an assignment is much better done with a `for` loop where you declare a local variable for the loop invariant. Only works, though, if you don't need the last line later on in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
void some( int b ) {
    int a = 0;
    if(  a = b ) {
       // or do something with a
       // knowing that is not 0
    } 
    // b remains the same 
 }
```

Comment: what if b is zero here?  Do we still know that a is not zero inside?

Comment: If b is zero, a remains 0 and doesn't go into the if code.

Comment: Ohh, of course :P The integer 0 being treated as false always confuses me with c.

Comment: Just replace the body of the function with `int a = b; if(b) {}` Clearly, I don't get the point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there a case where the warning
>   should be ignored because it's a good
>   way to use this "feature"? I don't see
>   any code clarity reason possible so is
>   there a case where its useful?

The warning can be suppressed by placing an extra parentheses around the assignment. That sort of clarifies the programmer's intent. Common cases I've seen that would match the (a = b) case directly would be something like:

```
if ( (a = expression_with_zero_for_failure) )
{
    // do something with 'a' to avoid having to reevaluate
    // 'expression_with_zero_for_failure' (might be a function call, e.g.)
}
else if ( (a = expression2_with_zero_for_failure) )
{
    // do something with 'a' to avoid having to reevaluate
    // 'expression2_with_zero_for_failure'
}
// etc.
```

As to whether writing this kind of code is useful enough to justify the common mistakes that beginners (and sometimes even professionals in their worst moments) encounter when using C++, it's difficult to say. It's a legacy inherited from C and Stroustrup and others contributing to the design of C++ might have gone a completely different, safer route had they not tried to make C++ backwards compatible with C as much as possible.

Personally I think it's not worth it. I work in a team and I've encountered this bug several times before. I would have been in favor of disallowing it (requiring parentheses or some other explicit syntax at least or else it's considered a build error) in exchange for lifting the burden of ever encountering these bugs.

Comment: +1 I always automatically add the extra parentheses. But _if_ I forget, what compilers will _not_ warn me, given that I always set the warning level quite high?

Comment: If my vote counted (in my dreams), I'd vote to require it to be a build error without the parentheses or some other explicit syntax in a conditional expression (while/for/if/ternary operator?:). Then we don't have to care about warning levels.

Answer (score 1):

### Preamble

Note that this answer is about C++ (I started writing this answer before the tag "C" was added).

Still, after reading [Jens Gustedt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122284/in-which-case-is-ifa-b-a-good-idea#comment3206176_3122409), I realized it was not the first time I wrote this kind of answer. Truth is, this question is a duplicate of another, to which I gave the following answer:

*[Inadvertent use of = instead of ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of/400644#400644)*

So, I'll shamelessly quote myself here to add an important information: **`if` is not about comparison. It's about evaluation.**

This difference is very important, because it means anything can be inside the parentheses of a `if` as long as it can be evaluated to a Boolean. **And this is a good thing.**

Now, limiting the language by forbidding `=`, where all other operators are authorized, is a dangerous exception for the language, an exception whose use would be far from certain, and whose drawbacks would be numerous indeed.

For those who are uneasy with the `=` typo, then there are solutions (see **Alternatives** below...).

### [About the valid uses of if(i = 0) [Quoted from myself]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of/400644#400644)

The problem is that you're taking the problem upside down. The "if" notation is not about comparing two values like in some other languages.

The C/C++ `if` instruction waits for any expression that will evaluate to either a Boolean, or a null/non-null value. This expression can include two values comparison, and/or can be much more complex.

For example, you can have:

```
if(i >> 3)
{
   std::cout << "i is less than 8" << std::endl
}
```

Which proves that, in C/C++, the if expression is not limited to == and =. Anything will do, as long as it can be evaluated as true or false (C++), or zero non-zero (C/C++).

### About valid uses

Back to the non-quoted answer.

The following notation:

```
if(MyObject * p = findMyObject())
{
   // uses p
}
```

enables the user to declare and then use *p* inside the *if*. It is a syntactic sugar... But an interesting one. For example, imagine the case of an XML [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)-like object whose type is unknown well until runtime, and you need to use [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information):

```
void foo(Node * p_p)
{
    if(BodyNode * p = dynamic_cast<BodyNode *>(p_p))
    {
        // this is a <body> node
    }
    else if(SpanNode * p = dynamic_cast<SpanNode *>(p_p))
    {
        // this is a <span> node
    }
    else if(DivNode * p = dynamic_cast<DivNode *>(p_p))
    {
        // this is a <div> node
    }
    // etc.
}
```

RTTI should not be abused, of course, but this is but one example of this syntactic sugar.

Another use would be to use what is called C++ variable injection. In Java, there is this cool keyword:

```java
synchronized(p)
{
   // Now, the Java code is synchronized using p as a mutex
}
```

In C++, you can do it, too. I don't have the exact code in mind (nor the exact *[Dr. Dobb's Journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Dobb%27s_Journal)*'s article where I discovered it), but this simple define should be enough for demonstration purposes:

```
#define synchronized(lock) \
   if (auto_lock lock_##__LINE__(lock))

synchronized(p)
{
   // Now, the C++ code is synchronized using p as a mutex
}
```

(Note that this macro is quite primitive, and should not be used as is in production code. The real macro uses a `if` and a `for`. See **sources** below for a more correct implementation).

This is the same way, mixing injection with `if` and `for` declaration, you can declare a primitive *foreach* macro (if you want an industrial-strength *foreach*, use [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29)'s).

### About your typo problem

Your problem is a typo, and there are multiple ways to limit its frequency in your code. The most important one is to make sure the left-hand-side operand is constant.

For example, this code won't compile for multiple reasons:

```
if( NULL = b ) // won't compile because it is illegal
               // to assign a value to r-values.
```

Or even better:

```
const T a ;

// etc.

if( a = b ) // Won't compile because it is illegal
            // to modify a constant object
```

This is why in my code, `const` is one of the most used keyword you'll find. Unless I *really* want to modify a variable, it is declared `const` and thus, the compiler protects me from most errors, including the typo error that motivated you to write this question.

But is there a case where the warning should be ignored because it's a good way to use this "feature"? I don't see any code clarity reason possible so is there a case where its useful?

### Conclusion

As shown in the examples above, there are multiple valid uses for the feature you used in your question.

My own code is a magnitude cleaner and clearer since I use the code injection enabled by this feature:

```
void foo()
{
    // some code

    LOCK(mutex)
    {
       // some code protected by a mutex
    }

    FOREACH(char c, MyVectorOfChar)
    {
       // using 'c'
    }
}
```

... which makes the rare times I was confronted to this typo a negligible price to pay (and I can't remember the last time I wrote this type without being caught by the compiler).

### Interesting sources

I finally found the articles I've had read on variable injection. Here we go!!!

- *[FOR_EACH and LOCK](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401723?pgno=6)* (2003-11-01)
- *[Exception Safety Analysis](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401728)* (2003-12-01)
- *[Concurrent Access Control & C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401752)* (2004-01-01)

### Alternatives

If one fears being victim of the `=`/`==` typo, then perhaps using a macro could help:

```
#define EQUALS ==
#define ARE_EQUALS(lhs,rhs) (lhs == rhs)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int a = 25 ;
   double b = 25 ;

   if(a EQUALS b)
      std::cout << "equals" << std::endl ;
   else
      std::cout << "NOT equals" << std::endl ;

   if(ARE_EQUALS(a, b))
      std::cout << "equals" << std::endl ;
   else
      std::cout << "NOT equals" << std::endl ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

This way, one can protect oneself from the typo error, without needing a language limitation (that would cripple language), for a bug that happens rarely (i.e., almost never, as far as I remember it in my code).

Comment: I like how you mix in that foo() example as a blatant violation of LSP.

Comment: +1, excellent answer. To point out one part I like - note about lhs being a constant for `==` is particularly good advice.

Comment: Just for the records, the reasons given in the first part only apply to C++, not to C. C99 allows for the declaration of variables only in a `for` statement. For your trick to avoid this common error: well I find constants on the left not easy to read. For me this is a bit as if you were advertising `10[a]` instead of `a[10]` ;-) Frankly, I think the compiler warning is good enough.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: I agree. This is why I wrote "RTTI should not be abused". Sometimes, you just don't have the right tools (visitor, access to objects) to use a more correct OO way.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: When I started this answer (and lost a lot of time trying to track the right Dr Dobbs article on variable injection), the tag was still C++, which explain I don't even considered C here. Still...

Comment: @paercebal: sorry, didn't notice that the C label had been added on the fly.

Comment: When thinking of it, for C++, I am not really convinced of your arguments, and even technically you are kind of wrong since you are talking about initialization of variables, and not of assignment. 
I think the question targets assignment, `operator=` in C++, and my understanding of C++ is that `operator=` and a constructor with one argument are quite distinct.
So my idea would be in that case to avoid the `=` completely by using the function-like initialization systematically: don't use `operator=` in conditionals.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: The main argument here is "In C/C++, the `if` notation is not about comparing two values, it's about evaluating an expression". It is perhaps too much powerful, but an expression can have multiple appearances, and forbidding the `=` in the if just because of some random error is overkill. The fact I declare a variable in the `if` is an example of a valid case where and `=` operator can appear in a `if` (even if it is resolved as through constructor)

Comment: You don't give examples for the `operator=` but for constructors. The fact that constructors with one argument can also be called by means of the `=` syntax is an historical corner case of C++. Agreed that `if` is about expressions, but you were not adding for the cause that it is good style to have `operator=` in these expressions. You don't give one example of even a use of it. BTW, even in the macro example you give, you use yourself the function notation.

Comment: When i saw the first two big captions, i so knew the answer is by @paercebal :)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb : Thanks for the compliment... ^_^ ...

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Other people already contributed by giving the examples you want to see. My point is that if the `if` is all about evaluating expressions, then there is no way to remove the `operator=` without crippling the language. And what's the point of crippling the language just because of a typo? Personally, I can't even remember this bug biting me.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: ... And I believe you take the `if(a = b)` too literally. My examples uses the constructor even if writting `=`, Ok, but this is not a corner case of C++. It is how C handles initialization of primitives. The C++ corner case would be the constructor/cast notation. It could be used, of course. But I see no point in forbidding `=` just because some people fear typos, when other dangerous notations, like the C-casts, are still authorized as they are in C++.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: ... Conclusion : My examples were about showing there were more between a `if` parentheses than a simple comparison, and showing that one just couldn't question about the presence of an operator because of its supposed potential for errors, and should instead see the larger picture around it.

Comment: @paercebal: The question was not: *should we cripple C++ (or C) to not allow assignment in an `if` expression?* It clearly targeted (in C++ terms) `operator=` and asked whether or not this was a good idea. You just didn't convince me, personally, for the simple reason that you didn't answer the question, but a different one. I still think that it is generally a bad idea to use it, and that the gcc-habit to put extra parenthesis is a good way to make intentions clear. That's it.

Comment: @paercebal i've not really read the content (i'm no good at coding styles), but i know you are the man of using big captions for each chapter of your answers :) So i immediately knew it was yours after reading the first of the two ^^

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: I understand your viewpoint, but I disagree with your strict limitation of answering about `operator =` because I do believe the subject is larger than that. So I guess we agree on the fact that we disagree... ^_^ ...

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I took it as a compliment/recognition of my answering style... ^_^ ...

Answer (score 0):

**Never!**

The exceptions cited don't generate the compiler warning. In cases where the compiler generates the warning, it is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

There's an aspect of this that hasn't been mentioned: C doesn't prevent you from doing anything it doesn't have to.  It doesn't prevent you from doing it because C's job is to give you enough rope to hang yourself by.  To not think that it's smarter than you.  And it's good at it.

Comment: its if(a==b) not what you said

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx sample

```
RegEx r;

if(((r = new RegEx("\w*)).IsMatch()) {
   // ... do something here
}
else if((r = new RegEx("\d*")).IsMatch()) {
   // ... do something here
}
```

#### Assign a value test

```
int i = 0;
if((i = 1) == 1) {
   // 1 is equal to i that was assigned to a int value 1
}
else {
   // ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is:

```
if (CComQIPtr<DerivedClassA> a = BaseClassPtr)
{
...
}
else if (CComQIPtr<DerivedClassB> b = BaseClassPtr)
{
...
}
```