# Why am i not getting the prime numbers instead getting all the numbers from 2 to 98?

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,p,f=1;
    printf("Prime Numbers till 99: \n");
    for (p=2;p<99;p++)
    {
        for (i=2;i<p;i++)
            if(p%i==0)
            {
                f=0;
                break;
            }

        if(f=1)
            printf("%d ",p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why am i not getting the prime numbers instead getting all the numbers from 2 to 98 ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is predicated upon a typo and will have no relevance for future readers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell There is slightly more than that one typo, but you are right in that it will likely not be of much relevance to anyone in the future.

Comment: Multiple errors of that sort really only decrease the likelihood of usefulness, @arshajii, since the chance that someone else makes the same combination goes down.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I do agree, and voted to close accordingly.

Comment: if you might do `if(1==f)` instead of `if(f==1)` then misspelled `=` instead of `==` will give an error Read: [Variable assignment in `“if”` condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition/17681607#17681607)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes here.

1. `if (f=1)` needs to be `if (f==1)` or simply `if (f)`. Remember, `=` is assignment; `==` is comparison.
2. You need to set `f` back to `1` at the end of each loop iteration. Otherwise `f` will be `0` forever after the innermost `if`-statement is first entered, and only the first prime number will be printed.

---

```
int main() { 
    int i, p, f = 1;
    printf("Prime Numbers till 99: \n");

    for (p = 2; p < 99; p++) {      
        for (i = 2; i < p; i++) {
            if (p%i == 0) {
                f = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (f) {  // here
            printf("%d ", p);
        }

        f = 1;  // and here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Prime Numbers till 99: 
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(f=1)` should read `if(f==1)`. The assignment always evaluates true.

Comment: Guys got my mistake, except condition operator in f