# Checking if an item is already in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

So I want to do some error checking on a vector that I have in a class to see if the item already exists before adding the new item to the vector.

ClassA cpp

```
void ClassA::func(std::shared_ptr<ClassB> new_item)
{
    for(auto items : vector_)
    {
        if(items = new_item)
        {
            return;
        }
        vector_.push_back(new_item);
    }
}
```

vector_ is the member class member std::vector. With this current implementation all new_item are being ignored even if it is not a duplicate. I know that 'if(items = new_item)' is the problematic line but I do not know why.

Comment: First, try `==` instead of `=`. Next, have a look at `std::find`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable assignment in "if" condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition)

Comment: Doesn't this have undefined behaviour because `push_back` may reallocate and then the iterators used by the range-based for loop will be invalid? Not to mention that it will add the new item many times.

Comment: Another reason why you should use const iterators, const & arguments. when you intend to read (compare, in your case). Had you used const iterators you wouldn't have been here posting this question :)

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes.  It will probably fail in strange ways from time to time.  (And when it doesn't fail, he's likely to get a lot of unwanted extra copies of the item.)

Comment: This is going to be O(N²).

Comment: You should be using `std::set`, not `std::vector`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are assigning instead of comparing for equality here:

```
if(items = new_item) // assigns value of new_item to items
```

This kind of problem is easily avoided by using well tested standard library functions such as [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
....
if (find(vector_.begin(), vector_.end(), newitem) == vector_.end())
  vector_.push_back(newitem);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
if(items = new_item)
```

should be

```
if (items == new_item)
```

Btw you may write

```
if (std::find(std::begin(vector_), std::end(vector_), new_item) == std::end(vector_) {
    vector_.push_back(new_item);
}
```

or use a `std::set`

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment

`==` is equality

You want

```
    if(items == new_item)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
void ClassA::func(std::shared_ptr<ClassB> new_item)
{
    for(auto items : vector_)
    {
        if(items == new_item)
        {
            return;
        }            
    }

    vector_.push_back(new_item);
}
```

Note that you need `==` rather that `=`. Also, your code was adding `new_item` to the vector on every iteration. Now it's just done if the item isn't found.

Comment: You're probably also going to want to do `auto const&`.

Comment: What he needs is `if ( std::find( vector_.begin(), vector_end(), new_item ) == vector_.end() ) { vector_.push_back( new_item ); }`.  There's no point in reimplementing what's already in the standard library.  (What he also needs is another naming convention.  Underscores as leading or trailing characters is just bad.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - yes, but I'm trying to show what's wrong with the code

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't see how it's bad. I do the same to identify private members of a class more easily.

Comment: This will have the advantage of working, but is still inefficient.

Comment: @CashCow - that's quite a claim. What makes looping over `vector_` less efficient that calling `std::find`?

Comment: Both are wrong. Use a std::set or unordered_set. If you want to maintain the insertion order then have a set on the side.

Comment: @Sean It's not the looping itself, but making an unnecessary copy every iteration that makes it inefficient. Refer to the first comment under you answer.

Comment: No it's the looping that makes it inefficient. If you are adding 1000 items then you are going to make 999 checks on your last insertion, 998 the insertion before etc. Thus 500,000 checks. If you used a std::set it would be approx 1000 * 10 = 10,000.

The copying might be inefficient depending on the class itself.

Comment: @ctor Leading and trailing underscores are easily overlooked, and disappear with some fonts.  If you want to identify data members, then `myXxx` or `m_xxx` do the job quite well.

Comment: @CashCow Now that _is_ inefficient.  If the vector is large, efficiency is an issue, and you don't need to maintain insertion order, you can keep it sorted, and use `std::lower_bound`.  `std::set` is convenient, but it certainly isn't efficient.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes efficiency in one area is inefficiency elsewhere. If there are likely to be just a few duplicates, insertion order is not an issue, and you need to maintain the compactness of a vector, you just push_back everything then at the end, sort and remove dupes. unordered_set is more efficient for avoiding dupes during insertion time. Far more of an issue for me than the OP's coding style.

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't need to tell you this because I know you are very experienced. But keeping it sorted as you insert means inserting in the middle which is O(N) time to move the elements.

Comment: @CashCow And using `std::set` means allocating a new node for every insertion.  In our time critical components, we've banned node based containers, because of their poor performance; you can do a lot of copying in the time you're not spending in page faults.  We use `std::vector<std::pair<>>`, rather than `std::map`, for performance reasons. (The classical big-O analysis assumes that all accesses have constant time.  Which just isn't true.)

Comment: @CashCow (and everyone else): I agree that `std::set` is (or should be) the initial approach.  It's the most natural, requires the least code, and is the simplest to understand.  My comments only address the relative performance issues; it was suggested that using `std::vector` was a grave error for reasons of performance, which is false.  When performance is an issue, you'll have to measure, but in our case, we found a sorted `std::vector`, using `std::lower_bound` for the insertion, to be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
 if(items = new_item)
    {
        return;
    }
```

value of new_item is assigned to items as "=" is an assignment operator and anything positive to if will make the condition true. You need to use "==" operator for comparison