# OOP static variable changing value

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

I recently came upon this code in a comic, which I did not understand. Can someone please explain this to me? Is there any reason why the variable should change it's value?

```
static bool isCrazyMurderingRobot =  false;

void interact_with_humans(void) {
   if (isCrazyMurderingRobot = true)
      kill(humans);
   else 
      be_nice_to(humans)
}
```

Here is the comic: http://oppressive-silence.com/comics/oh-no-the-robots

Comment: Simple put, you can do assignment in conditions with some languages.  See this question for an example of such: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18450261/2127492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be that in many programming languages, 
checking for equality is done by using `==`, while using a single `=` sign would assign the value to the variable).

So the code

```
if (isCrazyMurderingRobot = true)
```

would assign `true`to the variable and the first condition will always be satisfied (as the result of the assignment would be true).

The correct line would be:

```
// use  '==' here instead of '=' to check if variable is set
// using a single '=' would assign the value instead
if (isCrazyMurderingRobot == true)
```

For more details, please check these descriptions (they are for the C# language, but the operators behave similar in other languages like Java etc...)

[assignment (=)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)  operator.
[equality (==)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) operator.