# the value of a float variable is going to the wrong if condition

Tags: c++

[image]

the value of a float variable is going to the wrong if condition.. doesnt matter if thats a 0 or a -1.. it is just going for the condidtion when variable is to +1

Comment: can you post code?

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image of the code

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy-paste the actual code, as text, into the body of the question instead. And [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The issue is that you're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparative operator `==`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `==` instead of `=`.

In `c++`, assignment operator (`=`) returns the value equal to the assigned value (this allows writing something like `a = b = c`). That's why `slope = 1` is equal to `1`, which, when converted to `bool`, equals `true`, and so you end up entering the `if` section.

Comment: thank you soo much .. i m soo stupid

Answer (score 2):

Your assigned value in condition, not check it. First you use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between = and ==. In your if statement you want to check the value, hence you should use ==.

```
if(slope == 1)
{
/*...*/
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much .. i m soo stupid

Answer (score 0):

The following lines in your code are invalid:

```
    if (slope = 0)
    if (slope = +1)
    if (slope = -1)
```

This is because you use the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`. As a result of this, your if-statements are not making the desired comparison between the `slope` and the values +1, 0, or -1.

If we have to compare 2 values, 2 variables, or a variable to a value in an if-statement, then we use the equality operator `==` to compare them over the `=`. There are a few exceptions to this; see the following page:
[**Variable assignment in “if” condition**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition).

Just a side note, I would like to point out that you should use some more whitespace in your code; it helps make it more readable. Also, try posting the code itself in your question instead of posting a snapshot of it.

Good luck!