# Is declaring a pointer and assigning the result of a realloc to it as an if argument valid in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, realloc

I am trying to implement the Dijkstra algorithm, and I first need to design a graph structure with variable number of nodes; in order to do so, I'll need to dynamically change the size of an array of structures, and I wanted to know if writing this :

```
if( !(struct s *a = (struct s *)realloc(some_pointer_to_s_struct, new_size*sizeof(struct s))) ) {
    return -1; //because that means my pointer is NULL
}
//do something
```

is correct in C, because according to this post : [answer to a post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition) it is.

However when I tried to change my code to match that pattern, I get plenty of `error: expected ‘)’ before xxx` and other errors of the sort...
I thought that maybe I forgot to match a bracket or a parenthesis at first, but I spent a good 30 minutes reviewing my code, and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: The post you link is **C++**. C is a **different language**. They are similar enough, but you can't deduce something is valid in C just because it's valid in C++ (or vice versa). Beyond that, your attempt is not valid C++ either.

Comment: Each line of code - just do one thing at a time. Makes things easier to read and understand.

Comment: In C [you shouldn't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), unlike C++

Comment: Really? Is it bad practice or just not necessary?

Comment: read the link, everything has been explained clearly there[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question is about C++ and not about C.  In C it isn't possible.

---

BTW your code isn't valid C++ either as it tries to use a negation on the declaration.

Comment: Yes but the answer, was for C and C++, but you were right it was the negation of the declaration was causing the issue!

Comment: @Balocre - At no point did the poster of the accepted answer claimed it's valid C.