# Recursive binary search returns correct target, but at the middle index in array

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, search, binary

Trying out a recursive binary search algorithm, it returns the correct target that I pass it but at the wrong index.

The index seems to always be the center index of the high and low values.

I added some printf's in the binarySearch if statements, and it seams it never calls itself recursively, always returns with the mid value.

Even if you change the target to a value not held within the array, it returns with index 5, and the correct target value.

```
int main(void)
{
    int const numbers[10] = {1,3,4,7,13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 23};
    int const target = 20;
    int result = 0;
    result = binarySearch(&numbers, 0, 10, target);
    if (result != -1)
    {
        printf("Element is found in array in index: %d, and holds value: %d\n", result + 1, numbers[result]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Element is not found in array\n");
    }
}

int binarySearch(int* arr, int low, int high, int x)
{
    if (high >= low)
    {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] = x)
        {
            printf("mid\n");
            return mid;
        }
        else if (arr[mid] > x)
        {
            printf("high\n");
            return binarySearch(arr, low, mid - 1, x);
        }
        else if (arr[mid] < x)
        {
            printf("low\n");
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1 , high, x);
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Element is found in array in index: 5, and holds a value of: 20
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Did your compiler not whine about the `if (arr[mid] = x)` ?  Did you mean `==` ?

Comment: compiling on server of Linux that my college provides, editing with Visual Studio 2019. didn't get any warnings but doing this solved my problem. Do you have a greater understanding why this would solve? (still new to C, and trying to be proficient in it)

Comment: As far as C is concerned, an assignment is an expression, whose value is the result of the assignment.  So in `if (arr[mid] = x)`, `x` is assigned to `arr[mid]`, the result of the expression is the new value of `arr[mid]`, ie 20 in this case, which is _true_ as far as C is concerned.  With `==`, on the other hand, the expression returns `1` if the values on either side are equal.  It's a standard _gotcha_ in C.  FWIW, doing a binary chop by recursion is a little exotic -- a loop will do the job.

Comment: Also: I think the initial call of `binarySearch()` should be `0, 9` not `1, 10` -- C arrays are `0` origin.  You need to think carefully about what `low` and `high` refer to in `binarySearch()`.

Comment: would using sizeof(array) return the correct length of the array = 9?

Comment: Up to a point... `sizeof(numbers)` will give you the size of the array in *bytes*, in this case, probably 40.  `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` will give you the size of the array in elements, in this case 10.  Noting that that's the size allocated, not the number of elements in your static initialisation `{ 1, 3, ... }`.  I'd change the `binarySearch()` to take `const int* arr`parameter -- which would then be consistent `const numbers[]` argument.

Comment: Related: *[Variable assignment in “if” condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition)*

Comment: Re "Linux": Presuming GCC, [`-Wall` would catch it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition/151869#151869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple mistake**

As far as C is concernced `arr[mid] = x` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Since `x` is does not return to a 0, the if statement gets cleared and returns the wrong index, but the correct value.
If we change the target to 0, the if statement returns false, and it doesn't return the mid index.

We need to change `arr[mid] = x` to `arr[mid] == x` to change it from a assignment to a comparison.