# Calling string.find() function and assigning its return value to variable inside if condition

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I have trouble understanding what's exactly happening when i put .find() function inside if condition. Similar call in for loop seems to work good.

Part of my code goes like this:

```
    size_t endPos = strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size();
    cout<<endPos<<endl;

    if (size_t endPosif = strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size() != string::npos)
    {
        cout<<endPosif<<endl;
    }

    for (size_t endPosfor = strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size();endPosfor != string::npos; 
        endPosfor=strbuf.find(startSeq,endPosfor+1)+endSeq.size())
    {
        cout<<endPosfor<<endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
466
1
466
```

What causes this behavior? I would like to use endPosif inside if statement.

Comment: You should do one thing at a time, or at least use `()` to enforce correct order of operations. Also note that result of `strbuf.find(` must be checked to figure out whether it did found anything *prior* to any other use.

Comment: This is wrong: `strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size() != string::npos` condition will always pass. Same `endPosfor != string::npos` since it is set to `endPosfor=strbuf.find(startSeq,endPosfor+1)+endSeq.size()`.

Comment: @MarekR Right. It's just example if statement I did to show what's my problem is.

Comment: So please provide [mcve] you can use this site: https://wandbox.org/ to provide such example

Comment: @user7860670 When I have ( ) like these ` if (size_t endPosif = (strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size()) != string::npos) ` it's still the same result

Comment: @MarekR I would like to know why my variable equals 1 inside statement. That was my question

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know why my variable equals 1 inside statement. That was my question

```cpp
if (size_t endPosif = strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size() != string::npos)
```

this `strbuf.find(endSeq)`

- returns `string::npos` (which is like `-1`) when nothing is found
- or something in ragne `<0, strbuf.size() - endSeq.size()>`

When you add to that `endSeq.size()` (what is never zero) result is always different then `string::npos`.

So this `strbuf.find(endSeq)+endSeq.size() != string::npos` is evaluated to `true`.

`true` is converted to `1` when cast to `size_t`.

So you have two bugs:

- incorrectly handling scenario when nothing is found
- evaluation order (that is why `user7860670` wrote about parenthesis)

Comment: When I delete part  `+endSeq.size()` endPosif still equals 1. I read this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition) so I assumed I can do initialization, assigment and condition check in one step, so i dont unerstand why this syntax doesn't work. At the moment I have workaround that looks like this `if (size_t endPosif = strbuf.find(endSeq); endPosif != string::npos)` and works fine.

Comment: Ok. I read (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-if-condition)  again and i found this: _The only drawback with this approach is that you can't use it when the variable is declared in the condition. That is, you cannot rewrite:_ `if (int x = Foo()) { ... }`  as `if ((int x = Foo()) != 0) { ... }` . So i think this is answer to my question. Tank you for help either way