# match and search in struct and mark true or false C

Tags: c, search, struct, match

I'm building a system of 2 servers and 1 client for reservations.
I found an obstacle, now I'll explain:
-server A
-server B
-client

Once the client selects from a menu what he wants to book and when,
server B must look in the struct for the date and check if it is available, if it is send an ok, if it is not send a no as an answer.
To do it I had thought of the following way, but it does not work:

```
bool search(int bet2,  bool flag)
    {
     int i=0;

      for(i=0; i < 11; i++){
        if(strcmp(content[i].date, content[bet2].date) == 0)
        {
           if (content[i].mark == true)
           {
               printf("Date Busy");
               return false;
           } else {
               content[i].mark = true;  
               printf("Date booked day: %s",content[i].date);   
               return true;
            }}
      }
    }
```

in the prototypes I declare it so:

```
bool search (int bet2, bool flag);
```

in the main I declare it so:

```
search (bet2, flag);
```

the struct is this:

```
typedef struct choice {
    char name [40];
    char date [40];
    bool mark;
} Choice;

Choice content [10];
```

now I have a doubt, but the type bool exists in C?

anyway, where am I wrong?

sorry but I'm writing lines of code this morning and I'm stuck here, probably I do not see it.

this code return ever that date is good, where am i wrong?

Comment: That is not the code you compiled, not even a part of it. At least the `Else` would make an compiler complain. Please turn this into a MCVE.

Comment: sorry guys, but as I did the copy and paste it has pasted so, it's not my fault and I did not notice, I posted directly, after the post is edited by yunnosch

Comment: Please note, people here can tell that the error was not done by me. Maybe you want to rephrase that comment.

Comment: @Rock.: Yunnosch did a good job editing the question and before that I edited it - nobody added that extra `}` apart from you. Don't blame like this.

Comment: @Rock.: Again you make your code unformatted.

Comment: Apart from insisting on improvable code formatting, you also gave a problem description "it does not work". Please elaborate on that, maybe giving some details of behaviour in contrast to desired behaviour.

Comment: @Rock.: You edited the question - and now you have modified your question looking at my answer.. Dont edit the question like this after answered!

Comment: This has now become a "moving target question". This is quite a reliable way of discouraging potential answerers. I feel with you @coderredoc.

Comment: you asked me for the correct code I ran and I glued it and I apologized for the first time because I did copy and paste and the text was glued incorrectly.

Comment: Congratulations, the last edit has introduced a conflict between parameter and local variable, both called "flag", but of different type.

Comment: give me time to fix things, otherwise it is useless for you to write it down

Comment: Please, pleae. Create a correct [mcve], including a good error decription. Doing that right away would have avoided the (from your point of view) unhelpful answer and would have avoided the conflicts you create by editing manually.

Comment: it is useless to do the pundits, if you want to help do not be vain, otherwise avoid commenting

Comment: For the purpose of having time to edit your question in peace, delete it, edit it, double-check it, then undelete it when you are really done.

Comment: ok i clean, but the code not work correctly

Comment: this function not return the bool

Comment: there's no "return" statement at the end of the method. if the loop ends without calling the inner return statements, behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content [i] .mark = true
```

will be

```
content [i] .mark == true
```

To avoid this kind of problem you can use the comparison like this

```
true == content [i] .mark
```

In this case even if you forget the `==` and use `=` the compiler will complain.

And yes even better is to use simple and easy to read

```
  if( content [i] .mark )
```

Also there is no keyword called `Else` in C. It will be `else`.

Remove the extra `}` in the code where you have written `}}`. The scoping changes for that and it is wrong.

Also why use `return flag = false` it's useless here. Just do `return false` or `return true`. Because `flag`'s changed value won't be used anywhere.

Comment: `true == content`, aka Yoda conditions (in case OP wants to look it up).

Comment: @CookiePLMonster.: what you mean? My answer just mentioned where it went wrong using `=` insread of `==`..I see .. I have mentioned that - Let me know if there is anything I missed

Comment: this fix is correct

Comment: yes but it isn't a solution of my question

Comment: @Rock.: You edited the question...

Comment: @Rock.: To answer yes there is `bool`  in c -- you can check teh standrad and your other question is answered already

Comment: no because the code not work correctly

Comment: @Rock.: I have answered you mentioning the problems in this aprt of code - if you have problem in other code how do u expect me to correct it? Ask a new question I will help. Check the naswer..all problem is being discussed

Comment: As a potential contributor to this topic, I don't know what the question is about anymore. Good job.

Comment: @coderredoc what do you expect by answering stupid typo questions like this? You have your C gold, use it by selecting a good dupe instead of answering.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Well it turned out to be bad. The answer delivered is providing the right information to solve along with good practice. Done my job. It is hard to find dupe for these questions.

Comment: no it's _not_ difficult: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399792/inadvertent-use-of-instead-of