# More concise way to write the following statement

Tags: c++

Is there a more concise way to write the following C++ statements:

```
int max = 0;

int u = up();
if(u > max)
{
 max = u;
}

int d = down();
if(d > max)
{
max = d;
}

int r = right();
max = r > max ? r : max;
```

Specifically is there a way to embed the assignment of the functions return inside the if statement/ternary operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that:

- The idea was to remove the local variables (i.e. you don't need `u`, `d`, `r` later on)
- Evaluation order doesn't matter

... then you can just use `std::max`:

```
int m = max(max(max(0, up()), down()), right());
```

If this is the return value of the function:

```
return max(max(max(0, up()), down()), right());
```

Note that that can evaluate the functions in any order, rather than the string up, down, right order in your original code.

Comment: what about u, d, r variables ?

Comment: @bortao: I was assuming that the entire point of the question is to render them unnecessary.

Comment: If you really need the variables, @Bortao, then assign them just like in Alan's code and use them in place the function calls in Jon's code. It might not just be a matter of aesthetics, either. They could be important to guarantee order of evaluation. In Jon's code, `right` might be evaluated before `up` and `down`, even though the original code has it evaluated last.

Comment: @Rob: Right - I couldn't remember the details of evaluation order in C++. Will edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
...

int maxn = max(max(up(), down()), right());
```

If I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed assignments, but not variable declarations within the if statements:

```
int max = 0, u, d, r;

if ((u = up()) > max)
  max = u;

if ((d = down()) > max)
  max = d

max = (r = right) > max ? r : max;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
max = std::max(right(), max);
```

Comment: Out of interest, where do the side-effects come in? Surely each function is going to be executed exactly once either way, right? Admittedly the *ordering* becomes important in my answer - but in your statement here, there's no concern about ordering as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct!  I was thinking of the C macro.  Edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
int u = up(), d = down(), r = right();
int max = (u > d) ? u : d;
max = (max > r) ? max : r;
```

> Specifically is there a way to embed the assignment of the functions return inside the if statement/ternary operator?

IMO That would produce terrible legibility

Answer (score 1):

I'd write something like this:

```
int max = 0;

maximize(max, up());
maximize(max, down());
maximize(max, right());
```

Where `maximize` takes the first variable by reference, and a second variable as an offering. If the offering is greater than the first variable, then the first variable is set to the offering.

```
void maximize(int& v, int offering) {
   if (offering > v) {
      v = offering;
   }
   // or use std::max
}
```

---

#### Benefits

The other alternative to `maximize` is this one-liner nested-`max` expression:

```
// nested-max alternative; more "functional" style
int v = max(max(max(defaultValue, val1), val2), val3);
```

Contrast this with the multi-step refinement maximization process:

```
// multi-step maximize alternative; more "imperative" style
int v = defaultValue;
maximize(v, val1);
maximize(v, val2);
// perhaps do something else in between...
maximize(v, val3);
```

Though not as concise, this latter approach offers the following:

- A linearized form can be more readable than a deeply nested `max` expression
- You can do something in between each maximization steps if you need to
- The order of the maximization steps are explicit

  - It's also easily to reorder by moving individual statements around

---

#### On assignment in condition

And now we address the following part of the question:

> Specifically is there a way to embed the assignment of the functions return inside the if statement/ternary operator?

If you insist on doing something like this, you can always use a temporary variable as follows:

```
int offer;

if ((offer=up()) > max) {
  max = offer;
}
if ((offer=down()) > max) {
  max = offer;
}

max = ((offer=right()) > max) ? offer : max;
```

This does not result in a very readable code in this case, but there are idiomatic ways to use an assignment in a condition in some scenarios.

#### Related questions

- [Why would you use an assignment in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that if the execution order of up,down and right is not important, then this sequence should be used:

```
max(max(0,up()), max(down(),right())
```

because it minimizes result dependencies and should execute faster on common super scalar CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

The more generic problem is finding the max of the given inputs. We can generalise `std::max` to something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
T Max (const T && input_1, const Ts && ... inputs)
{
    // initialise:
    T max = input_1;

    // find max:
    ([&] (T i)
    {
        if (i > max)
            max = i;

    } (inputs), ...);
    
    return max;
}
```

(above is `c++17` style, but we can write the same thing in a less pretty way in earlier `c++`)

This makes finding the max like so:

```
int max = Max<int>(0, up(), down(), right());
```

We add the `<int>` to specify what we want to convert the inputs to, in case some are `unsigned`, `float`, etc.

If the order of calls actually does matter, then there's not much better we can do than this:

```
int max = 0;
max = std::max(max, up());
max = std::max(max, down());
max = std::max(max, right());
```

We *could* make a generic function, like `Max` above, that takes in a list of functions/functors instead, but it's such an unusual issue that I doubt you'd re-use the code.