# Converting an int or String to a char array on Arduino

Tags: string, char, arduino

I am getting an int value from one of the analog pins on my Arduino. How do I concatenate this to a `String` and then convert the `String` to a `char[]`?

It was suggested that I try `char msg[] = myString.getChars();`, but I am receiving a message that `getChars` does not exist.

Comment: Do you really need a modifiable array? If not, you could use `const char * msg = myString.c_str();`. Unlike `toCharArray()`, `c_str()` is a zero-copy operation, and zero-copy is a good thing on memory-constrained devices.

Comment: @EdgarBonet It works, but only for one string at time. Last c_str() overwrite older.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

1. To convert and append an integer, use *[operator +=](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator)* (or member function `concat`):

   ```
    String stringOne = "A long integer: ";
    stringOne += 123456789;
   ```
2. To get the string as type `char[]`, use [toCharArray()](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray):

   ```
    char charBuf[50];
    stringOne.toCharArray(charBuf, 50)
   ```

In the example, there is only space for 49 characters (presuming it is terminated by null). You may want to make the size dynamic.

#### Overhead

The cost of bringing in [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) (it is not included if not used anywhere in the sketch), is approximately 1212 bytes of program memory (flash) and 48 bytes RAM.

This was measured using Arduino IDE version 1.8.10 (2019-09-13) for an [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers) sketch.

#### Risk

There must be sufficient free RAM available. Otherwise, the result may be lockup/freeze of the application or other strange behaviour ([UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Comment: Saved me a lot of tinkering time. Thanks! In order to make the char[] size dynamic, do something like
`char charBuf[stringOne.length()+1]`

Comment: I did it dynamically like this:
 `char ssid[ssidString.length()];` 
 `ssidString.toCharArray(ssid, ssidString.length());`

Comment: @loeschg Thanks, I tried without the `+1` at first, but your solution worked for me!

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365434/edit-comments-on-tickets-discussion.html?childToView=397510#comment-397510

Comment: BIG WARNING! I learned the hard way, if you're intent is to get a partial string, let's say the first character only to use in a switch/case statement, you need to allocate enough for the whole string, otherwise the function returns and leaves your buffer empty - and you scratching your head and ending up in this forum.

Comment: Though 48 bytes RAM is suspicious close to the buffer size. This needs to be investigated. Coming up.

Answer (score 62):

Just as a reference, below is an example of how to convert between `String` and `char[]` with a dynamic length -

```c
// Define 
String str = "This is my string"; 

// Length (with one extra character for the null terminator)
int str_len = str.length() + 1; 

// Prepare the character array (the buffer) 
char char_array[str_len];

// Copy it over 
str.toCharArray(char_array, str_len);
```

Yes, this is painfully obtuse for something as simple as a type conversion, but somehow it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 24):

You can convert it to char* if you don't need a modifiable string by using:

```cpp
(char*) yourString.c_str();
```

This would be very useful when you want to publish a String variable via MQTT in arduino.

Comment: very useful. I got mine working passing arguments to: 
NTPClient(UDP& udp, const char* poolServerName);

was struggling with converting String to char*.

Answer (score 1):

None of that stuff worked. Here's a much simpler way .. the label str is the pointer to what IS an array...

```
String str = String(yourNumber, DEC); // Obviously .. get your int or byte into the string

str = str + '\r' + '\n'; // Add the required carriage return, optional line feed

byte str_len = str.length();

// Get the length of the whole lot .. C will kindly
// place a null at the end of the string which makes
// it by default an array[].
// The [0] element is the highest digit... so we
// have a separate place counter for the array...

byte arrayPointer = 0;

while (str_len)
{
    // I was outputting the digits to the TX buffer

    if ((UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0))) // Is the TX buffer empty?
    {
        UDR0 = str[arrayPointer];
        --str_len;
        ++arrayPointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: `str` isn't pointer to an array, it's a `String` object implementing the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 1):

With all the answers here, I'm surprised no one has brought up using itoa already built in.

It inserts the string representation of the integer into the given pointer.

```
int a = 4625;
char cStr[5];       // number of digits + 1 for null terminator
itoa(a, cStr, 10);  // int value, pointer to string, base number
```

Or if you're unsure of the length of the string:

```
int b = 80085;
int len = String(b).length();
char cStr[len + 1];  // String.length() does not include the null terminator
itoa(b, cStr, 10);   // or you could use String(b).toCharArray(cStr, len);
```