# How can I insert an integer into a block of memory?

Tags: c, memory

Is there any way I can put an integer into a string of known size and if yes how can I read it? For example an (int a=10) into a (char string[200]).

Comment: Can you clarify your question are you trying to convert 10 to a string "10" and then add it to your char array or put the binary representation in you array of bytes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can put an integer into a string of known size and if yes how can I read it? For example an (`int a=10`) into a (`char string[200]`).

**Yes, there is** use the string version of `printf`

```
snprinf(string,200,"%d",a);
```

It is also possible to generate the string with a loop with div and mod by 10 if you want to do above by hand. *See another answer for an example of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49615617/391691*

To get your int back from the string `sscanf`, `atoi` or `atol` can be used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
   int a;
   char string[200];


   a = 10;
   snprintf(string,200,"%d",a);
   printf("As string:%s As int:%d\n",string,atoi(string));
}
```

*The interpretation of this question is still not clear to me, this represents an alternative interpretation of the question compared to previous answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/58584291/391691*

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Could it be implemented with memcpy also?

Comment: `memcpy` would represent the other interpretation of this question where you just store the raw data in the char array -- which will at this point not be a string.

Comment: @Stelios if this is the right answer for you, please consider rephrasing you question to match the answer for future readers. I will then delete my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way I can put an integer into a string of known size and if yes how can I read it? For example an (int a=10) into a (char string[200]).

In this answer I work with the minimal question stated, which does not give details about any of the following:

- Representation / encoding of the integer in `string`
- Architecture this should run on
- The position where to insert the integer

If this question is about converting an integer to its ASCII representation the [answer by @Simson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58584528/3215929) is what you are looking for.

C allows you to "put"<sup>[1]</sup> an integer into any position of a c style string by casting the `char` array to an `int*`.

```
// string: the array (char*)
// pos: position in the array (size_t)
// to_insert: the value to insert (int)
(*(int*)(&string[pos])) = to_insert;
```

**But be warned**: This is a sledgehammer approach. You have to be very careful when doing this or your code might show undefined behavior on different platforms. For example you have to manually check and answer:

- *Memory alignment*: will I try to insert the integer at a position which is not addressable by the architecture?
- *Endianness*: is the way that I write this integer to the array actually what I want?
- *`sizeof(int)`*: does the integer still fit into the array? Maybe consider using any fixed length integer types such as `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, ...
- and possibly a few more

The following example shows the usage of the method discussed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert_at_pos(char* arr, size_t pos, int to_insert){
  (*(int*)(&arr[pos])) = to_insert;
}

int main(void) {
  char string[200] = {0};
  insert_at_pos(string, 3, 10);

  //print char by char as hex
  for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(string)/sizeof(*string); ++i){
    printf("%x ",(unsigned char)string[i]);
  }
}
```

Running the example:

```
$ ./main
0 0 0 a 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

[1]: And by "put" I understand write as-is.

Comment: In this example you make assumptions about the size of int to be 32 bit.

Comment: *You can do this by casting your `char` array string to an `int*`.*  No, you can not safely do that. `(*(int*)(&string[pos])) = to_insert;` violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule] and may also invoke undefined behavior per [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned68) for the referenced type, **the behavior is undefined**."

Comment: (cont) Just Google [`SIGBUS` ARM](https://www.google.com/search?q=sigbus+arm)

Comment: I just answered what the question was asking for: "Is there any way I can put an integer into a string of known size and if yes how can I read it?" Neither does the author say a single word about converting the integer to ASCII, nor does he state anything about `sizeof(integer)` or the position where to insert that int. I do know that my answer might cause undefined behavior on different systems but it tries to do exactly what the author is asking for.

Comment: Write a comment about the interpenetration of the question and address the issues pointed out  then this is good reference for someone in the future who have another interpretation of the question.