# Should I check if malloc() was successful?

Tags: c, error-handling, malloc, runtime-error, allocation

Should one check after each `malloc()` if it was successful? Is it at all possible that a `malloc()` fails? What happens then?

At school we were told that we should check, i.e.:

```
arr = (int) malloc(sizeof(int)*x*y);
if(arr==NULL){
    printf("Error. Allocation was unsuccessful. \n");
    return 1;
}
```

What is the practice regarding this? Can I do it this way:

```
if(!(arr = (int) malloc(sizeof(int)*x*y))
    <error>
```

Comment: In theory, yes.  In reality, if malloc fails the operating system is probably about to crash.   PS:  Your second example is much harder to read than the first and should be rejected by a code review.

Comment: `arr = (int) malloc(...)` is wrong, `malloc` returns a pointer. Apart from that: yes, you should check if it fails because it can fail. [Also, casting its return value is harmful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: 1. You do not need the cast. 2. Yes check - why not

Comment: @SteveWellens I would say that it is yes in theory and in practice, especially when big buffers are allocated.

Comment: @AlexD - True.   But if you are allocating a buffer so large that malloc may fail, then I would say a re-design is in order.

Comment: @SteveWellens Usually yes, I do agree. But one can come up with an application which uses "as much memory as possible". But my main reason to comment was that someone could misread your remark as "_in practice, do not check_". (It is another issue if one needs to add `if` to every `malloc` or just wraps it and terminate the application with a proper message.)

Comment: @AlexD - "in practice, do not check"  I would say, "in practice, **sometimes** it's fine not to check since it clutters up the code space and if allocating 10 bytes fails, your program has already crashed or is about to".   Note:  I write code to be as fault tolerant as possible:  I look both ways when crossing a one way street.

Comment: This question code has nothing to do with checking `malloc` or not as asked. Both code snippets check whether `malloc` is null. The difference is [whether to use an assignment inside a conditional or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would you use an assignment in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This mainly only adds to the existing answer but I understand where you are coming from, if you do a lot of memory allocation your code ends up looking very ugly with all the error checks for malloc.

Personally I often get around this using a small malloc wrapper which will never fail. Unless your software is a resilient, safety critical system you cannot meaningfully work around malloc failing anyway so I would suggest something like this:

```
static inline void *MallocOrDie(size_t MemSize)
{
    void *AllocMem = malloc(MemSize);
    /* Some implementations return null on a 0 length alloc,
     * we may as well allow this as it increases compatibility
     * with very few side effects */
    if(!AllocMem && MemSize)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return AllocMem;
}
```

Which will at least ensure you get an error message and clean crash, and avoids all the bulk of the error checking code.

For a more generic solution for functions that can fail I also tend to implement a simple macrosuch as this:

```
#define PrintDie(...) \
    do \
    { \
    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); \
    abort(); \
    } while(0)
```

Which then allows you to run a function as:

```
if(-1 == foo()) PrintDie("Oh no");
```

Which gives you a one liner, again avoiding the bulk while enabling proper checks.

Comment: Your `PrintDie` should call `abort`, not `exit`. Because it would be simpler to debug (on Linux, you'll even get a `core` dump, which you could analyze post-mortem with `gdb`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, had forgotten all about abort, changed the example to use it now.

Comment: `if(NULL == AllocMem)` is the wrong test.  With `MemSize == 0`, receiving a `malloc()` return value of `NULL` _is_ compliant behavior and not an allocation failure.  Changing to `if(NULL == AllocMem && MemSize != 0)` fixes that.

Comment: @chux You are correct there that that is desirable behaviour for most implementations, it is a little tricky in the standard as it says (in C99 and C11): "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined" (7.22.3 P1, ISO C11). However what you suggest is a common implementation in many compilers so I shall add a check to the code with a note. Thanks.

Comment: @Vality: That's a bit simplistic.  The POSIX standard [contains the same language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html), but then goes on to specify that the return value is *either* `NULL` or some non-null pointer which you can `free(3)` but not dereference. POSIX also conforms to the C standard in every respect except that it specifies setting `errno` on failure, which looks quite useless to me since `ENOMEM` is the only legal error code, but I suppose you could do `errno = 0; ptr = malloc(...); if(errno) abort()`. Still looks like a cheap party trick to me.

Comment: Basically reimplementing [xmalloc](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xmalloc&apropos=0)

Comment: @Ayxan it looks like it. Though I haven't seen xmalloc before as I've never developed on BSD. Looks like a useful function though. Thabks for the info.

Answer (score 13):

No need to cast `malloc()`. Yes, however, it is required to check whether the `malloc()` was successful or not.
Let's say `malloc()` failed and you are trying to access the pointer thinking memory is allocated will lead to crash, so it it better to catch the memory allocating failure before accessing the pointer.

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));
if(arr == NULL)
{
printf("Memory allocation failed");
return;
}
```

Comment: On a pedantic note, this answer promotes "check whether the malloc() was successful or not" - which is a good idea.  But then it shows how to check the result of `malloc(sizeof(int))` and not OP's `malloc(sizeof(int)*x*y)`.  Testing against `NULL` is sufficient for this `sizeof(int)`, but wrong for OP's  `sizeof(int)*x*y`.  Should `x*y` --> 0, a `NULL` return is compliant code and does not indicate a memory allocation.  Better to use `if(arr == NULL && x != 0 && y != 0)`.