# C - Allocating memory for char type array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have task to create char type array, and then enter number of elements that array should have, and after that allocate memory for that array and print it after entering all the elements into the array. Problem is, I know how to do it if array was int type, but for char I only for print of random charachters. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {


    int n, i;
    char *arrA;


    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter array elements: \n");
    arrA = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("Array element: %c \n", arrA + i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d. array element is: %c\n", i + 1, arrA + i);
    }

    free(arrA);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make it work for char type array?

Comment: `scanf("Array element: %c \n", ...)` looks very iffy to me.

Comment: @InternetAussie can you suggest better way to do it, it doesen't work anyway this way I wrote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complement to the other answers:

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int n, i;
  char *arrA;

  printf("Enter number of elements: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Enter array elements followed by [Enter] key: \n");

  getc(stdin);  // absorb \n (scanf oddity)

  arrA = malloc(n * sizeof(char));

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf("%c", &arrA[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d. array element is: %c\n", i + 1, arrA[i]);
  }

  free(arrA);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `scanf("%c"` to `scanf(" %c"` and the "`scanf` oddity" should no longer exist. If there is no whitespace, the space gobbles nothing. If there is whitespace, the space gobbles it all. And `sizeof(char)` is redundant, as it is alway 1.

Comment: @SvenB just enter the characters en press the [Enter] key only once at the end.

Comment: @InternetAussie not quite.  With "scanf(" %c"...` and no `getc`, the first element will actually be `10` (line feed from previous `scanf`).

Comment: That is odd. `scanf` is supposed to gobble `'\n'`s as whitespace.

Comment: @InternetAussie how does the program behave on your system? I admit, that I never really understood that scanf stuff, I never use it.

Comment: If I remove the `getc(stdin);` and change the `"%c"` to `" %c"`, then it just skips the whitespace, including any newlines between the input characters. The C standard specifies that `fscanf` (and `scanf` by extension) skips any characters where `isspace` returns non-zero if a whitespace character is in the format string. [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/mVEHUY) does this too, so I'm not the crazy one :p

Comment: @InternetAussie so I suppose my C implementation is the crazy one then (possible because it's Microsoft).

Answer (score 3):

Change line :

```
printf("%d. array element is: %c\n", i + 1, arrA + i);
```

to :

```
printf("%d. array element is: %c\n", i + 1, *(arrA + i));
```

or :

```
printf("%d. array element is: %c\n", i + 1, arrA[i]);
```

as right now you are trying to print the pointer itself and not its content.

Also read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) on why not to cast the result of `malloc` and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831981/should-i-check-if-malloc-was-successful) on checking `malloc`'s result.

Answer (score 2):

`arrA + i` is a *pointer*. You need to use `*(arrA + i)` in the `printf` argument, or the clearer and exactly equivalent `arrA[i]`.

Notes: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by the C standard, so is superfluous. Also don't cast `malloc` on the right hand side. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Lastly, always check the result of `malloc`. If it's `NULL` then the memory allocation failed.

Comment: Changed it as you said, but still I get random character print after entering number of elements, can't get to the phase where I input elements into array... And also I get error that arrA cannot be used without being initialized...