# How to pass argument array pointer in function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing

**I have this code:**

```
// *** foo.c ***

#include <stdlib.h> // malloc

typedef struct Node {
    char (*f)[20];
    //...
} Node;

int function(char f[30][20]){
    // Do some stuff with f...
}

int main(){
    Node * temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    function(temp->f[20]);
}
```

I would like to pass `temp->f` array pointer to function, but on compile I get these errors:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:16:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘function’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     function(temp->f[20]);
     ^
foo.c:10:5: note: expected ‘char (*)[20]’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
    int function(char f[30][20]){
        ^
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: expected 'char (*)[20]' but argument  is of type  'char *'

Comment: @uninopkn Which in turn should lead you to think "what `char*`, I passed an array pointer. Or wait... maybe I didn't..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expected 'char (*)[20]' but argument is of type 'char *
```

Change the way you call the function to:

```
function(temp->f);
```

Also:

- [Why you should not cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- [Why you should always check the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831981/should-i-check-if-malloc-was-successful)

Comment: How is that declaration any different from the original?

Comment: @Lundin you are right, I began writing something else but changed my mind.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know we weren't supposed to do what I did in the edit. Live and learn :)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array "f" as argument, you are passing its first item ADDRESS (as arrays are pointers)
But when you pass f[20] as argument, you are passing the VALUE of the 20th element 
of f

So, if you pass (f) (or temp->f in your case) you are passing an address and the destination shall be "char*" type to receive.

And if you pass f[20] (or temp->f[20]) you are passing a value and the destination shall be "char" type

If you want to receive the address of the 20th item, you should pass &(f[20]) ( or &(temp->f[20]) )

Just to clarify: "f" is equivalent to "&(f[0])", as both represents the address of the first item