# Decision is not working, 'if' and 'else if' in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

Today I learned about *if* and *else if*. So an idea came in my mind and I make a program, that takes six numbers and ask for a choice, so the adding decision work correctly, but other two also work as first decision. What is the solution?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main ()
{
    int a, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, adse, sum, sub;

    cout << "\nPlease Enter The First Number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "\nPlease Enter The Second Number: ";
    cin >> a1;
    cout << "\nPlease Enter The Third Number: ";
    cin >> a2;
    cout << "\nPlease Enter The Fourth Number: ";
    cin >> a3;
    cout << "\nPlease Enter The Fifth Number: ";
    cin >> a4;
    cout << "\nPlease Enter The sixth Number: ";
    cin >> a5;

    sum = a + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5;
    sub = a - a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5;

    cout << "\nPlease Select the chioce (1, 2, or 3)";
    cout << "\n1: Adding";
    cout << "\n2: Subtracting";
    cout << "\n3: Exit";
    cout << "\nPlease Enter Your Choice: ";
    cin >> adse;

    if (adse = 1)
    {
        cout << "\nThe Addition is : "<<sum;
    }
    else if(adse = 2)
    {
        cout << "\nThe Subtraction is : "<<sub;
    }
    else if(adse = 3)
    {
        cout << exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nSorry Wrong Choice, Program is Closing";
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Use a compiler that wasn't meant for close to 20 years ago and turn up the warning level.

Comment: Beginner-level mistakes in C or C++, like assignment instead comparison, e.g. `if (adse = 1)` here, ***should not be answered***. They should be closed as a duplicate of a canonical question (that also has much better answers). Or at least indicated (so others can close it). There is a canonical question from the first few days of Stack Overflow existence (September 2008). There is not even an indication here of what the canonical question might be.

Comment: The canonical is not easy to find. But it must be there somewhere. New trial: [List of the oldest C questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?tab=newest&page=7630&pagesize=50) (the oldest visible is from 2008-08-01 (from the private beta)). That doesn't work either (too advanced).

Comment: Candidate: *[Why would you use an assignment in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition/151869#151869)*. An answer says *"GCC can help you detect (with -Wall) if you unintentionally try to use an assignment as a truth value"*. But there be a better one, with a question more directly containing this problem.

Comment: Candidate: *[Why would you use an assignment in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition/151869#151869)*. An answer says *"GCC can help you detect (with -Wall) if you unintentionally try to use an assignment as a truth value"*. But there must be a better one, with a question more directly containing this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should use "==" instead of "=" in comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You need to use `==` rather than `=` when comparing statements. This is because in your example, `adse` is not being *compared*, but adse is being *set* to one, just like if you wrote `adse = 1;`.

Now bools are `true`/`false` statements, but when stored in memory represent a 0 for `false` and a `true` is 1. So when you test the state of a boolian you are actialy testing if its equal to one or not. Now for how this relates to your question. Because adse is being set to one, the if statement is the same as `if (true)` and will always enter. Because the first statement will always enter, the else statement will never execute and there-four will never run

To fix, replace `=` with `==` in conditional statements, like this:

```
if (adse == 1)
{
    ....
}
```

**Second**

Indent your code, it makes it much easier to read for others and yourself.

Comment: `the other two do not work because they are 2 and 3`: that's not the reason. http://ideone.com/wtaRFq -- they are not executed because the first branch is taken (note the `else if`s)