# C assignments in an 'if' statement

Tags: c

I came across this line of code written in C that confuses me coming from a JavaScript background.

```
short s;
if ((s = data[q])) 
    return s;
```

Is this assigning *s* to *data[q]*, and if it equals true/1, return s?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition)

Comment: basically it returns s as long as data[q] is != 0. In C, everything except 0 is true. (of course s is assigned data[q]).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, an assignment...well assigns...but it's also an expression. Any value not equalling zero will be evaluated as true and zero as false.

it would be the same as

```
if ((s = data[q]) != 0) return s;
```

Comment: "Evaluated as 1" is really confusing, it's more like "any non-zero value will be considered to be true".

Answer (score 7):

Your code is assigning `data[q]` to `s` and then returns `s` to the `if` statement. In the case when `s` is not equal to `0` your code returns `s` otherwise it goes to the next instruction.

Or better said it would expand to the following:

```
short s;
s = data[q];
if (s != 0)
    return s;
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting. So any other value than 0? Because what I learned from JavaScript is if (true) return something.

Comment: Every value which is not `0` is considered true in C.

Answer (score 2):

Basically C evaluates expressions. In

```
s = data[q]
```

The value of `data[q]` is the the value of expression here and the condition is evaluated based on that.

The assignment

```
s <- data[q]
```

is just a `side-effect`.

---

<sup>Read this [[ article ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) on sequence points and side-effects</sup>