# DRY when assigning new value each loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, dry, assign

Considering a function `query_item` that either returns an object to be processed or `null` if nothing is to be processed anymore.

```
let item = query_item();
while(item !== null){
    process(item);
    item = query_item();
}
```

Clearly, this is a small violation of DRY (Don't repeat yourself), mostly mitigated by having `query_item()` as a dedicated function.

I am aware that in this simple case, clarity is much more important than preventing repetition.

Nevertheless, **is there a way to write a loop like this without repeating the assignment?**

The only thing that I came up with was a for-loop approach, but that has the same repetition and is - in my eyes at least - a little harder to read.

```
for(let item = query_item();
    item !== null;
    item = query_item()
){
    process(item);
};
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition/151870#151870) might help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the standard scenario where one would use an assignment inside the `while` condition:

```
let item;
while (item = query_item()) {
    process(item);
}
```

or possibly, if you want to be explicit:

```
let item;
while ((item = query_item()) !== null) {
    process(item);
}
```

You also can use a `for` loop with the same approach, which also gives you block scope for `let`:

```
for (let item; item = query_item(); ) {
    process(item);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested that assignment?

Comment: @MatheusValienteSouza he has 250k rep, he doesnt need to, he *knows*

Comment: Ah right, I tried it with the declaration inside and that didn't work, but just the assignment seems to be perfect. @MatheusValienteSouza I don't see how that assignment couldn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @iFreilicht i still think that a declaration should be an expression that returns the assigned value, but thats how it is...

Comment: I had the same idea from @Bergi(the assignment whith the !==null condition), but it has not assigned the value correctly.  I'll try it again.

Comment: Just pointing out - for the language learners - that the first `while` and last `for` loop additionally terminate on encountering `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `false` and `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Little prettier?

```
let item;
do {
  item = query_item();
  if (item) process(item);
} while (item !== null)
```

Comment: I'd recommend `else break; } while (true)` to avoid repeating the test

Comment: That's doing the test twice, though. And when just using `if (item)`, you now have two different conditions for executing `process` and breaking the loop. @Bergi has a good solution for that, but it's hardly prettier than his answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely avoid this assignment weirdness and get the plainest possible loop syntax, you might consider using an [ES6 iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

```
function query_items() {
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return this;
        },
        next() {
            return {
                value: query_item(),
                get done() { return this.value === null }
            };
        }
    };
}

for (let item of query_items()) {
    process(item);
}
```

Or even better implement `query_items` as a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) right away.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [assignment within the loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43986308/1647737)...

```
let item;
while (item = query_item()) {
    process(item);
}
```

...is a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) which terminates upon encountering a `null` value:

```
function* iterate(cb) {
  let next = cb();
  if (next === null) return;
  yield next, yield* iterate(cb);
}

for (let item of iterate(query_item)) {
  process(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For javascript I believe you could write:

```
while(let item = query_item() && item){
    process(item);
}
```