# Visual Studio Code javascript validation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to get annoyed when I'm using if statements. Sometimes i'm a bit to fast and i only use one "=" in my **IF** statement and then run my code. At first glance there is nothing wrong, but as i use my application weird stuff is happening. Then I use some time to go through my code to figure out that i only used one "=" in my **IF** statement.

So i'd like to know why an **IF** statement with one "=" get valid?

I remember some time ago when visual studio code would let me know through validation that it wasn't a valid statement. Or is it a vs code change that allow users to use one "=" in their if statements? Or is it just valid code?

```
if (k = array[i])
{
    console.log(k);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid statement. However, it's very rarely what you actually want to do. A single equals is an assignment, which returns the value which was assigned:

```js
console.log(a = 'hello');
```

Almost always you want to use a triple equals `===` as it's typically the safest way to make comparisons.

As to when vscode stopped flagging this up as a problem, that depends on how you've got your vscode setup. It isn't strictly a problem but I'm sure there are some linters which would alert you to this as a problem. You'd need to provide some more in depth information as to what your vscode setup is, which is probably a separate question altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'll try to find some extension that will let me know when i forgot to put in the proper amount of "="

Comment: `eslint` has a rule called `no-cond-assign`, with the right config this would flag it up to you https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign

Comment: Just because i'm curios when would you use an assignment in an if statement, and it would make sense?

Comment: There are a few edge cases, I can't say I've ever run into them personally, but this answer goes through a few of them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition

Answer (score 3):

Try installing "VS Code JSHint extension" in your Visual Studio Code. If you are also interested you can use "vscode-tslint" for type script. It helps a lot.

Comment: JSHint works perfectly for my needs, now i won't screw up as much ;) Thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome. Can you please upvote if useful.